# Correct way of appending of elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have such block that will select some `#id` and will append `svg-element` into it:

```
 var graph = d3.select(elemId).append("svg")
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .append('g')
```

In this element I`m drawing some diagram, and I need to append text to it in such format:

[DIAGRAM Image][Descriptive text]

I do this with this stuff:

```
var label = graph.append("text")
    .attr('x', width + 10)
    .attr('y', height - 10)
    .text(Descriptive text)
    .attr('id', "text_label")
```

Then, I need to add a new text but it must stuck with previous text in such format

[DIAGRAM Image][Descriptive text][New Text]

But I can find the way to append it correctly , so I need to hardcode some pixels to make it real.

```
graph.append("svg:text")
    .attr('x', width  + 100)
    .attr('y', height - 10)
    .text('New Text')
    .attr('id', "text_label_red");
```

How can I correctly append my `[New text]` to `[Descriptive text]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the content of a single text element and then concatenate your new text, like so:

```
 var newText = label.text() + " More content"
 label.text(newText)
```

Or, you can select the label element if the variable is out of scope:

```
 var newText = d3.select("#text_label").text() + " More content"
 d3.select("#text_label").text(newText)
```

But it looks like you want to set a bunch of text elements, so you'll need to use .each() because that's will let you access the parent DOM element of each item in your selection using "this". Here you'll use selectAll, which will work with your id attribute but you should really declare a class attribute when dealing with a class of elements:

```
d3.selectAll("#text_label").each(function() {
 var newText = d3.select(this).text() + " More content";
 d3.select(this).text(newText);
 // You could also use this.innerHTML to use plain js
 // if you wanted your new text to be a different style, you can wrap it in a span in HTML
})
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is fixed now

```
var valueWidth = graph.node().getBBox().width + 10;
```

This line will measure width of my main svg object and it will add 10 points to prevent stacking of text fields. Then, i`m creating label which is appended with text:

```
var label = graph.append("text")
    .attr('x', width + 10)
    .attr('y', height - 10)
    .text(label_right)
    .attr('id', "text_label")
```

And my third block with text is appended to same svg element:

```
    graph.append("text")
    .attr('x', width + valueWidth)
    .attr('y', height - 10)
    .text(last_element.y)
    .attr('id', "text_label_red");
```

So I have as result:
[DIAGRAM]['Describtion label']['Data label']